Cannot enter debug mode
When I tried connecting my stm32 to my keil software, it returns an error cannot enter debug mode
When I tried connecting my board to my software it didn't connect successfully. How do I fix this error, I also tried unistalling and reinstalling the software but the problem persisted, now I am stuck in this loop. When I tried connecting my stm32 to my keil software, it returns an error cannot enter debug mode

Does it work if you use something like STM32CubeIDE or STM32CubeProgrammer? If not, maybe someone has set RDP on the STM32 so that the debug port is disabled.

What debug hardware are you using (ST-Link, Ulink2 or what?).  Is the connection JTAG or SWD? In the Debug settings connection dialog, does it detect a valid Coresight on-chip debug present? Post a screenshot of the dialog perhaps.  Try changing the connection setting to "Connect Under Reset" or try the other options if that does not work.  There are many possibilities given the insufficient information you have provided.

Please check if while installing Keil all dependencies for stm32 were installed properly.
